# PHP Outputting Data with Escape Sequences

Tags: php, escaping, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate retrieved data from the database into a table cell and make the URL clickable.

I am using the  tag with the an **href** attribute to achieve that, but for some reason it is not working and I'm presented with a blank table cell. Any idea why?

```
echo "<tr>" . 
         "<td>" . $historyData['Name'] . "</td>" . 
         "<td><a href=\"" . $historyData['URL'] . "\"/a></td>" .
      "</tr>";
```

Also tried

```
echo "<tr>" . 
          "<td>" . $historyData['Name'] . "</td>" . 
          "<td><a href="" . $historyData['URL'] . ""/a></td>" .
      "</tr>";
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I really, really would suggest to stop using capitalized letters in array indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an option to make a string with `'` and `"`.

```
if(isset($historyData['Name']) && isset($historyData['URL'])){
  echo "<tr>" . 
         "<td>" . $historyData['Name'] . "</td>" . 
         '<td><a href="' . $historyData['URL'] . '">title</a></td>' .
       "</tr>";
} else {
  echo 'Whoops, I made a booboo with my indexes..';
  print_r($historyData);
}
```

Then there is also the option of doing something like this:

```
echo "<td><a href='{$historyData['URL']}'>title</a></td>";
```

Note that you require to use the **not** literal string, `"`